# AngularJs input and datepicker css is not working

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

Im creating a tablet app and i need put DatePicker like AngularJS Demos (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) but it is not working, see the picture:

[image]

im put the css from Angular Material:

```
<link href="resource/css/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There is other problem, the layout directive is not working, i think it is the same problem.

Thanks
Argate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attached a link to a working version of the Angular date picker [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGWErm).

The app includes the following dependencies: `['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']`

These are the dependencies you must load externally with CDN's or internally with `bower`, `node` etc.

```
 <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the HTML code you want to include the date-picker:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content layout-padding="">

        <div layout-gt-xs="row">
            <div flex-gt-xs="">
                <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
            </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Make sure you have loaded the dependencies in your app in the correct order, e.g: `['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']` as well as in your `development.js` or `production.js` file depending which environment you are working in.

Here is how you would include your personalised CSS theme:
(If you do not include the theme as a config of the app then your HTML references to the theme will not work)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink', {
      'default': '400', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary intentions
      'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
      'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
      'hue-3': 'A100' // use shade A100 for the <code>md-hue-3</code> class
    })
    // If you specify less than all of the keys, it will inherit from the
    // default shades
    .accentPalette('purple', {
      'default': '200' // use shade 200 for default, and keep all other shades the same
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be a number of things, this is a layout that works:

```
<md-content flex layout-padding>
  <div layout="row" layout-align=" start center">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="App" md-placeholder="date" flex></md-datepicker>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Example:

[Angular Material App Layout](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/vXLPAx?editors=1010)

You might want to do a pen or fork the above and try to recreate your issue.